# after Mavericks OS upgrade, can no longer make any HTTP requests with the OPTIONS verb

Tags: ajax, http, curl, osx-mavericks, single-page-application

My machine can no longer make any HTTP requests with the OPTIONS verb.  This happens whether I try it curl, postman, or ajax.

curl -i -X OPTIONS http://www.google.com returns curl: (52) Empty reply from server

It should return a long string containing a 405 error code.

I suspect that this is related to the Mavericks "upgrade" I did earlier this week.  I only have one mac (my dev machine) with Mavericks.  Other macs are Mountain Lion and they don't have this problem.

Can anyone else with Mavericks confirm whether or not they have this problem too?

If this is Mavericks related, anyone know of a fix or workaround?

Comment: run it with -v and see that the request it sends looks good...

Answer (score 2):

Turns out that it wasn't Mavericks related at all.  Cisco AnyConnect has a security module running behind the scenes even when you're not VPNed into anything.   It was blocking my OPTIONS verb requests.  I was able to make these calls after uninstalling.

Re-installing with Web Security turned off should prevent it from happening.  While I was uninstalling I did notice that there was a web security uninstall script in /opt/cisco/vpn/bin but I already committed to taking the whole app off my machine.  Simply running that script could have done it too.

I must give credit to Ben Nadel.  It was his blog post that helped me fix this issue.

http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2559-Cisco-AnyConnect-VPN-Client-May-Block-CORS-AJAX-OPTIONS-Requests.htm?&_=0.10495476494543254#comments_44093